# Request: Network device parts images dataset

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, images

I'm working on a object tracking model and I'm looking for a suitable training dataset. It should contain pictures of parts of networks devices (or even the whole device), mainly ethernet and power sockets, buttons, switches, LEDs and antennas. Even if it's preferable it's fine if the dataset isn't annotated (i.e. labels, bounding boxes).

I'm aware that maybe such dataset isn't that easy to find therefore I'll gladly accept also suggestions on sites to scrape or other crazy ideas. Surprise me!

Thanks for your time, I rely on your wisdom!